# Optional parameter in newcommand

Tags: macros, optional-arguments

I have made a command

```
\newcommand{\mysec}[2]{%
 \textbf{#1} \\ #2
}
```

I use it with `\mysec{A}{B}`.

But sometimes I also want a third parameter. I could make a whole new command for those situations where I need 3 parameters. But I thought if I could handle it with an optional parameter in my original command?

So I have to check if the third parameter is set and how to print if it is set.

Comment: If you are trying to make up your own sectioning commands, this is the worst way. What should the third argument do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Optional parameters are in `[]` not `{}` and if using `\newcommand` always come first.

so

```
\newcommand{\mysec}[3][]{%
 \textbf{#2} \\ #3 #1%
}
```

allows

```
\mysec{aaa}{bbb}
```

or

```
\mysec[ccc]{aaa}{bbb}
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I check if it's empty? I have tried `\ifx#1\empty\else\MakeUppercase{#1}\fi`

Comment: @Jamgreen Lots of ways, there are questions on site about that:-) your suggestion tests `\empty` and `\else` if `#1` is empty, i would use `\ifx\relax#1\relax` which is true if #1 is empty as then `\relax` tests equal to `\relax`, if you need to protect against `#1` being `\relax` you need a bit more complicated, but normally you don't...

Comment: @Jamgreen note however if this is a section heading, better to use the section heading commands, just using `\\ ` allows page breaks after the heading and misses all the other features latex normally takes care of.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use `xparse` and `\RenewDocumentCommand` with provides easier ways to define macros with optional arguments

The argument specification `somo` says to use a starred (`#1`), optional (`#2`), mandatory (`#3`) and a final optional argument (`#4`), if needed.

Redefining the sectioning commands should be done with care since they provide a starred variant which is used for example in `\tableofcontents` as a 'heading'

Instead of `\@ifnextchar[` it's necessary to use `\IfValueTF{#2}{true}{#4}` to ask whether the optional argument `#2` was used or not.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}

\let\origsection\section

\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{somo}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \origsection*{#3}%
    \IfValueTF{#4}{%
      \textcolor{red}{You used the starred version and the 4th optional argument: }\textcolor{violet}{#4}%
    }{%
%      \textcolor{blue}{You used the starred version but omitted the 4th one}%
    }
  }{%
    \IfValueTF{#2}{%
      \origsection[#2]{#3}
      \IfValueTF{#4}{%
        \textcolor{red}{You used the optional 2nd and 4th. arguments: }\textcolor{violet}{#4}%
      }{%
        \textcolor{blue}{You used the optional 2nd argument but omitted the optional 4th one}%
      }
    }{%
      \origsection{#3}
      \IfValueTF{#4}{%
        \textcolor{red}{You used the optional 4th. argument: }\textcolor{violet}{#4}%
      }{%
        \textcolor{blue}{You omitted the optional argument}
      }
    }%
  }%
}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section*{Starred section}[With an optional argument]
\section{A section}
\section[Another section]{Another section with useless long title}
\section[Another section]{Another section with useless long title}[And again with an optional argument]
\section{A section}[With optional arg]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want the last be optional then use the TeX level for the new command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\mysec#1#2{\@ifnextchar[{\mysec@i{#1}{#2}}{\mysec@i{#1}{#2}[]}}%
\def\mysec@i#1#2[#3]{%
 \textbf{#1} \\ #2 
 \ifx\relax#3\relax \else \\ #3 \fi}% or whatever you want to do with #3
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\mysec{foo}{bar}

\mysec{foo}{bar}[baz]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! But to me it's not important which argument is optional

Comment: then use the solution from David with my `\ifx ...`

Comment: @Jamgreen: And which argument do you want to be optional?